# JQUERY / HTML5 Validation - unable to update the validation message dynamically

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

I have a textbox that needs to have its minimum value and the validation message changes dynamically. The issue is, I am able to change the minimum value but not its validation message.

See the example here http://jsfiddle.net/fLxgz9dn/305/

The textbox is initially configured to have a minimum value of 100 and a validation message that says "Please enter an amount below 100". Input a value in the texbox and click on the submit button you will see that the error message is displayed correctly.

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" pattern="\d*" required="required" min="100" data-msg-min=" Please enter an amount below 100" />
```

Now, There is a button on the page which allows the user to change the minimum value and the validation message to 1000

```
<button id="changeMinimumAmount" > Change the  minimum amount to 1000 </button> 

$("#changeMinimumAmount").click( function()
       {
           $('#amount').attr("min","1000"); 
           $('#amount').attr("data-msg-min",""please enter a value below 1000"");   
       }
    );
```

After clicking on this button, when you  input a new value in the textbox,  you can see that the textbox is now validating against 1000, however the error message is still not updated. It still shows the old error that says "Please enter a value below 100"

Does anyone know why  the error message is not being updated ?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the `data-msg-min` correctly BUT this does not change the `label` that is created by whatever resource you are using. So you have to change that `label` by adding it to the click event. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fLxgz9dn/306/). Below is how the HTML is rendered in the console.

```html
<form id="myform" novalidate="novalidate">
    Enter the amount:  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" pattern="\d*" required="required" min="1000" data-msg-min="please enter a value below 1000" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" class="error">
    <label id="amount-error" class="error" for="amount">please enter a value below 1000</label>    
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't solve the problem.Follow the steps below.          
1) Input a value below 100 into the textbox and click submit. You will get the error message says "Please enter a value below 100"

2) Click on the "Change Minimum Amount" button

3) clear the textbox, input a new value for (example 700) and click submit. Error message is now gone back to the old one thet says  "Please enter a value below 100"


For some reason when it validates, It is always using the original validation message that was rendered when the page was initially loaded